# Is it possible to view only deleted files in eclipse SVN team synchronization?

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, myeclipse

I want to view only deleted files when synchronizing my changes which is currently showing all types of files - updated, added, deleted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is no way to do this directly with either the Subclipse or the Subversive plug-ins. However, both have the ability to remove a changed file/folder from the synchronize view (which doesn't actually change the actual status of the file/folder). Select one or more files/folders, right click and select Remove from View. In this way, you can show only deleted items, though it's a manual process and you can't remove a folder from the view if you want to retain a file within the folder. You can restore items removed from the view, via the view menu.